# bootstrap modal does not show,only showing backdrop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have posted this before but no one has reply me on my problem. However, after trying for few days. I encountered something funny.

My View Code

```
<% provide(:title, "Log in") %>
<div class="center jumbotron">
<h1> Kaching </h1>
<div class = "row" >
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :logID, "Log ID" %>
    <%= f.text_field :logID %>

    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.submit "Log In", class:"btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

When i include the  code, the modal box will appear when i load the page. However, my modal still will not appear when i press the button. I do not understand why. It will only work when i include bootstrap.js in my /assets/javascripts folder. However, this affects my tab that i implement on my other page. I try loading just the bootstrap-modal.js file, but it did not work also. Please guide me on this.

Thanks

Comment: bootstrap-modal.js required bootstrap.js to work, i checked the code in fiddle, there is nothing wrong with your code, you have to include bootstrap.js for modal to work https://jsfiddle.net/9900hykr/

Comment: Bootstrap.js has conflict with another javascript i implement for my tabs.how can i go about doing this?

Comment: I would suggest you to open a new question and describe the problem in detail and post the relative code, at this point i don't have any clue what the other javascript is and whatever i say will be just a wild guess

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32720836/error-with-javascript-and-bootstrap-js The javascript that i say is inside the script tag. It is to keep my tab in place when i place on the pagination links.please help me with it. It stops working when i include the bootsrap.js file